# What is wrong here? Why PHP OR it isn't working?

Tags: php

Here I have a little piece of code in PHP to deny access to one page except you came from two (page 1 and page 2). But it isn't working because it doesn't run the code at all.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://www.example.com/access.html' or $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://example.com/php/upload.php'){
    header ('Location: http://example.com/php/retry.php');
    exit;
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Remind that `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` [cannot really be trusted](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is always `true`, use `in_array` or `&&`.

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://www.example.com/access.html' && $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] != 'http://example.com/php/upload.php') {
    header(...);
}
```

or

```
if (!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], array('http://www.example.com/access.html', 'http://example.com/php/upload.php')) {
    header(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also should add a check if `HTTP_REFERER` is `empty` or not -

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], array('http://www.example.com/access.html', 'http://example.com/php/upload.php')) {
    header(...);
}
```